# Build a second camera into an ipod

Tags: hardware, ipod

My ipod has a selfie camera but not a second camera.

Can you actually build a camera into an iPod?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! We have a guide on how to ask excellent questions. I've edited out some of the text that doesn't help - feel free to edit in more details if you don't get a good answer.

Answer (score 2):

**No**, even if you managed to physically connect the camera to the device in that way, iOS would not interact with it as it is an iPod touch without such a camera.